# Executing the default application assigned to a file type, from terminal, given only file name

Tags: linux, gnome

Using gnome terminal (Ubuntu 10.10), is there a way to execute the default application associated to a file type, only by typing its name, as it is possible with Windows ?

For example, say I create a mime type associated to every file with the pattern *.abc. Lets say I associate this file type to application 'my_app'.

If I have file 'my_file.abc' in current folder, what I want is that when I enter only 'my_file.abc' at the prompt, it executes 'my_app' feeding it with 'my_file.abc' as first argument. 
(assuming of course 'my_app' is in the path)

I appreciate this behaviour in Windows, wondering if Linux/Gnome could do that too.
Thanks

Comment: You might have better luck on askubuntu

Comment: Well, yes, actually, I didn't know askubuntu until now. Is there a way to "switch" this post to askubuntu ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [binfmt_misc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binfmt_misc) facility for something similar, but you're probably better off just passing it to `xdg-open`.

Comment: Very interesting, I'll investigate this tool, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

On Linux with `zsh` (http://www.zsh.org/) you could achieve it in this way:

```
$ alias -s abc=my_app
```

And after it `zsh` will always execute `my_app youfile.abc` when you just enter youfile.abc.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any unix shell that allows you to execute any file in this way.

On Debian or Ubuntu, `see myfile` or `edit myfile` opens a file in the application that's associated to the file type through the mailcap mechanism. The command is from the `mime-support` package, which I think is installed by default on both Debian and Ubuntu (and anyway it's in many packages' dependencies, so it's probably installed already).

On many systems, you can use `xdg-open myfile` from the [xdg-utils](http://portland.freedesktop.org/wiki/) suite. This opens the file in the application that's associated to the file type through the [Freedesktop](http://www.freedesktop.org/) mechanism. The Ubuntu package is `xdg-utils`, also probably installed already.

Comment: Yeah, xdg-open works fine, I was only trying to see if what was possible on Windows could be transposed to Linux ;-) I struggled a bit with binfmt_misc, but couldn't get it to work in a seimple way, i.e.:
echo ':txt_file:E:*.txt:::/usr/bin/gedit::' > /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/register
but this doesn't work on my machine... I guess it wasn't designed to do such things in the beginning.

Comment: And by the way, do you guys know if there is any difference between "see" and "xdg-open" ? They both seem to use the system's mime database...

Comment: @kebs: `see` uses exactly the system's MIME database (including `~/.mailcap`. I think `xdg-open` uses a completely different FreeDesktop-specified database, but Debian and Ubuntu packages tend to populate both these databases.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `gnome-open` for that. Works pretty well for me.